# Yarn and mbtiles2gpkg

Tags: gdal, mbtiles

I installed node and yarn in Windows 10, but after adding mbtiles2gpkg I was getting error:

```
"mbtiles2gpkg" is not recognized.
```

Note: As this is environment variable Path issue I checked the path and `yarn --version` is displayed from cmd, power shell and nodejs cmd.

Comment: Do you mean that something in this installation process failed https://github.com/DenisCarriere/mbtiles2gpkg?

Comment: I couldn't infer anything to say about the current issue. It was easy to use yarn and then adding mbtiles2gpkg for further usage but I recall I used yarn.exe instead of CMD and node. Yarn.exe says another error but former way has to work as well.